# How to select the first X DIV's

Tags: jquery

I have e.g. 8 DIV's (containing images) in one row. My problem is that I want to be able to get a new row after X (this number is set in a slider) DIV's. In case of these 8 DIV's I want to add a new row after e.g. 4 DIV's.

My DIV's look like:

```
<div id="table-cell-x" class="table-cells"><img src="...."></div>
```

Where x = 1 --> 8

The result I want is (in case of 8 DIVs and X is set to 4):

```
<div class="table-rows">
    <div id="table-cell-1" class="table-cells">div1</div>
    <div id="table-cell-2" class="table-cells">div2</div>
    <div id="table-cell-3" class="table-cells">div3</div>
    <div id="table-cell-4" class="table-cells">div4</div>
</div>

<div class="table-rows">
    <div id="table-cell-5" class="table-cells">div5</div>
    <div id="table-cell-6" class="table-cells">div6</div>
    <div id="table-cell-7" class="table-cells">div7</div>
    <div id="table-cell-8" class="table-cells">div8</div>
</div>
```

I tried it with:

```
$('div.table-cells':lt(4)).append( '<div class="table-row"></div>' );
$('div.table-cells':gt(4)).append( '<div class="table-row"></div>' );
```

But that did not work........can you please help me with this problem....

Regards,
John

Comment: As i understand it, you want: `$('div.table-cells:eq(3)').after( '<div class="table-row"></div>' );`

Comment: Thx......was a typo when adding my question. Tried the selector also by adding a css "background-color" in stead of appending div-construction. Background-color did not show so I quess the selector is still not correct.

Comment: The result I want is:

    <div class="table-row">   
    <div id="table-cell-x" class="table-cells"><img src="...."></div>
    </div>

And after 4 cells (x>=5):

    <div class="table-row">   
    <div id="table-cell-x" class="table-cells"><img src="...."></div>
    </div>

Comment: That's still quite unclear what you want. Edit your question with current **&** expected HTML markup

Comment: Just edited it!

Comment: Ok BUT IDs must be unique on document context! So you want: `$('div.table-row:eq(3)').after( '<div class="table-row">...</div>' );` ?! EDIT: now i guess you want to wrap some table cells inside table row?! I'm still confused. Please, post more relevant markup than just single ones. We need to see your relevant HTML markup and then the one you want with x divs

Comment: @AlivetoDie For sure it would make more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i come to understand that you want each 4 `div.table-cells` will wrapped inside a container `table-row` div.

***If yes then do like below:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $child_div = $("div.table-cells");
  for (var i = 0; i < $child_div.length; i += 4) {
      var $parent_div = $("<div/>", {
          class: 'table-row'
      });
      $child_div.slice(i, i +4).wrapAll($parent_div);
  }
});
```

```css
.table-row{
 background:grey;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-cell-1" class="table-cells">div1</div>
<div id="table-cell-2" class="table-cells">div2</div>
<div id="table-cell-3" class="table-cells">div3</div>
<div id="table-cell-4" class="table-cells">div4</div>
<div id="table-cell-5" class="table-cells">div5</div>
<div id="table-cell-6" class="table-cells">div6</div>
<div id="table-cell-7" class="table-cells">div7</div>
<div id="table-cell-8" class="table-cells">div8</div>
```

Reference:-

[.wrapAll() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Comment: I understand that OP just wants to add one DIV. Btw, he seems to want to append a table row after a table cell. His question is very unclear to me

Comment: @A.Wolff   i have edited my assumption as well as code too

Comment: Ya, this makes more sense than what OP was asking :)

Comment: Thx!.......I will check later this day (have to go shopping now ;-)).......let you know the result!

Comment: Thx a lot!! Works perfectly!

P.S: after shopping I had to go to work (working in late shift as a meteorologist ;-) )